# Lookup and return value based on sub-string match

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Is there a formula or script that will match sub-strings from one column in another column and return the full value of the sub-string match? e.g.

**Input**

```
COL_a            COL_b
name             201284_blah_year.ext
address          407284_blah_name.xml
journal          501283_blah_journal_entries.ott
journal_entries  701284_blah_type.dat
year             401184_blah_journal.ext
type             301287_blah_address.txt
```

**Desired output**

```
COL_a            COL_b
name             407284_blah_name.xml 
address          301287_blah_address.txt
journal          401184_blah_journal.ext 
journal_entries  501283_blah_journal_entries.ott 
year             201284_blah_year.ext 
type             701284_blah_type.dat
```

Comment: Trying to figure out a macro or formula, but you can always just use text filters one by one depending on how many records there are

Comment: ideally it could support 100s.1000s of value

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&A1&"*")>0, TRUE,FALSE)` will give you a true or false depending on if the sub string is found in the array, just need to return the found value for true

Comment: @Raystafarian - would you suggest rolling it in VBA instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On **Column C**, write the below formula:-

```
=VLOOKUP("*_"&A2&".*",B:B,1,FALSE)
```

and then drag down this till end.

For your quick reference, below is my screenshot

[image]