# How to lookup a string within a column of substrings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data file, where there is a table like this:

```
(DATA TABLE)
           REF_ID              |     COST    |   TYPE
======================================================
123_COMPUTER_XYZ               | 50000       | (to be filled)
45623_LAPTOP_AOS               | 90000
BHJ_WALLET_ASODO               | 1000
BUIGQ32_TRIMMER                | 200
...
```

Now, I want to add another column to the table, wherein the `type` of the product is automatically put using a lookup table, which I have defined as follows:

```
(TYPE TABLE)
PRODUCT SUBSTRING    |  TYPE
=====================================
COMPUTER             | computer
LAPTOP               | computer
WALLET               | personal
TRIMMER              | personal-care
...
```

I want to use the `PRODUCT SUBSTRING` column in the TYPE TABLE as a lookup and put the corresponding value of `TYPE` into the
3rd column of the DATA TABLE.

I've looked at many questions:

- [Find Substring Within Column - Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/566838/find-substring-within-column-excel)
- [Lookup and return value based on sub-string match](https://superuser.com/questions/385801/lookup-and-return-value-based-on-sub-string-match)
- http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8800-substring-search-within-array-strings-part-2-a.html

but all of them ask it the other way round, wherein the string to be searched (REF_ID field) is a **sub-string** of the TYPE-TABLE.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a short *UDF()*.

Say the lookup table is in columns **F** and **G** from row *1* up to a maximum of *100* rows.  First insert this *UDF()* in a standard module:

```
Public Function GetType(sIN As String) As String
   Dim LookupTable As Range, nItems As Long
   Set LookupTable = Range("F1:G100")
   nItems = 100

   For i = 1 To nItems
      If LookupTable(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For
      If InStr(1, sIN, LookupTable(i, 1)) > 0 Then
         GetType = LookupTable(i, 2)
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next i
   GetType = "UN-FOUND"
End Function
```

Then in cell **C1**, enter:

```
=GetType(A1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student, it worked like a charm :) I was a little dicey stepping into VB scripting, but it seems to be a better way rather than jumping through a long string on function soup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem:

`=INDEX(Table2[TYPE],MAX((ROW(Table2[PRODUCT SUBSTRING])-1)*SIGN(IFERROR(SEARCH(Table2[PRODUCT SUBSTRING],[@[REF_ID]]),0))))`
This is an array formula, you need to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

where:

- `IFERROR(SEARCH(Table2[PRODUCT SUBSTRING],[@[REF_ID]]),0))` checks which substring is included in the actual REF_ID (gives starting position for it, 0 for all other substrings)
- `SIGN(...)` - converts previous list to `1` for found substring
- `(ROW(Table2[PRODUCT SUBSTRING])-1)` - row number minus one (position in the list if header is in first row)
- `MAX(...)` - as only value for the found substring is non zero, this function extracts it's position
- `=INDEX(Table2[TYPE],MAX(...))` - type from the list

[image]

### Update

Above formula refers to tables, to convert your ranges to tables select: **Insert - Table** *(in the example `table1` is the one at the left side, so convert it first)*

Formula with standard references:
`=INDEX(G$2:G$7,MAX((ROW(F$2:F$7)-1)*SIGN(IFERROR(SEARCH(F$2:F$7,A3),0))))`

Comment: Hi @Máté Juhász, thanks for your answer and explaination. I am not able to understand the [@[REF_ID]] part, and Excel is giving me some error when I try to paste your formula in the cell: `The syntax of this name isn't correct`

Comment: @kumar_harsh: please see my updated answer