# Excel FIND.VERT with partial text in a keyword table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find

I need a particular function and I think that it doesn't exists in standard Excel and probably I need a custom VBA function.

This function should do something like FIND.VERT but with particlular lookup to find partial text in the target string.

```
=MYCUSTOM.FIND.VERT(A1;KeyTable!A:B;2;SpecialPartialLookup)
```

This is the target cells (? is the place of the formula):

```
+----------------------------------+---+
| Text with some keyword somewhere | ? |
| Another test for this function   | ? |
| I'm not very imaginative now     | ? |
+----------------------------------+---+
```

and a keyword table:

```
+------------------+-----------+
|     KEYWORD      |   VALUE   |
+------------------+-----------+
| somewhere        | adverb    |
| test             | noun      |
| very imaginative | adjective |
| very imaginative | dontknow  |
+------------------+-----------+
```

This is what I want:

```
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|               TEXT               | RESULT    |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| Text with some keyword SOMEWHERE | adverb    |
| Another TEST for this function   | noun      |
| I'm not VERY IMAGINATIVE now     | adjective |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

(uppercase is only to show the match)

Is it possible?

Comment: It's very difficult to assess what you're asking when you describe your problem in terms of a function that does not exist. Still, `MATCH()` supports wildcards, it sounds like that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Infact I think I need a custom VBA function. But I would like to know if someone found the same problem.

Comment: This question is very similar to yours, except it doesn't require VBA: http://superuser.com/questions/1014156/how-to-lookup-a-string-within-a-column-of-substrings/1014164#1014164

Comment: @MátéJuhász thank you, seems exactly my question, I prefer VBA solution for a sharper control with wildcards, but that answer is very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
Function VerticalMatch(Value As Range, Matrix As Range, Index As Integer) As Variant
    Dim baseText As String
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0
    baseText = LCase(Value.Item(1).Value)


    For Each cell In Matrix.Columns(1).Cells
        x = x + 1
        If baseText Like LCase(cell.Value) Then
            VerticalMatch = Matrix.Columns(Index).Rows(x).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    VerticalMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

This works like Find.Vert but using a "like" comparison.

So the input has to be filled with wildcards:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|     KEYWORD        |   VALUE   |
+--------------------+-----------+
| *somewhere         | adverb    |
| *test*             | noun      |
| *very imaginative* | adjective |
| *very imaginative* | dontknow  |
+--------------------+-----------+
```