# Excel search function search term from other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search

I have an excel sheet with a function which uses the `SEARCH` function in the following way:

`=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("TERM1";MYCELL;1);0) > 0;IFERROR(SEARCH("TERM2";MYCELL;1);0) > 0;IFERROR(SEARCH("TERM3";MYCELL;1);0) > 0);MYVALUE;0)`

The problem is that each time if I have a new search term I need to update this function and recalculate all my values. So what I basically look for is a function something like this:

`=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH((st!A1:st!A3);MYCELL;1);0) > 0;MYVALUE;0)` where A1:A3 contains all the terms I like to search and its on the st (search terms) sheet.

How could I solve this?

**Update:** I guess my question was misunderstood. Here's a more detailed explanation.
What I'd like to do is tracking my expenses. I have an export from my bank with all my transactions and each transaction have a description about who was the target. I can group my targets by expense categories.
So I have a sheet which contains my groups by columns:

```
Food       | Gas
MCDONALDS  | Shell
BURGER     | Esso
KFC        | OMV
FRIDAYS    |
```

On another sheet I have my transactions from my bank and depending on what was the target I copy the amount for the proper category column

```
TARGET                | AMOUNT |  FOOD | GAS 
XY MCDONALDS COMPANY  | 10     |   10  |  0
12ShellXYZ            | 20     |   0   |  20
KFCEUROPE             | 50     |   50  |  0
```

Now this is implemented like my search example but it's hard to update when I make transaction for a new target. It would be simplier if my search terms come from the list explained above.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: have a look on these questions, I think the solutions are applicable for your case too: http://superuser.com/questions/566838/find-substring-within-column-excel, http://superuser.com/questions/385801/lookup-and-return-value-based-on-sub-string-match

Comment: Finally I managed to solve this problem based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803944/excel-searching-for-multiple-terms-in-a-cell